# Running into an error "cannot find table1" while using table1 package in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a table 1 per the instructions here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html, but running into this error:

```
    Error in table1(~factor(14) | Q21, data = dataset) : 
  could not find function "table1"
```

This is how I downloaded the package:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("benjaminrich/table1")
install.packages("table1")
```

Anything I could be doing wrong? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: After installation did you load the package with `library(table1)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah that was all I needed! Thank you!